# Trouble using catchError with RxFire firestore collectionData

Tags: rxjs, redux-observable, rxfire

I want to be able to respond to errors from a call to collectionData. I added a catchError but it never gets called.  In fact, the collectionData emits a result with no elements.

```
export const bundleEpic = action$ => action$.pipe(
  ofType(BUNDLES_LOAD),
  tap(action => console.log(`Received action: type=${action.type}`)),
  switchMap(() => (
    collectionData(bundlesRef, 'id')
    .pipe(
      tap(docs => console.log(`bundleEpic: size = ${docs.length}`)),
      map(docs => publicBundlesLoadSuccess(docs)),
      catchError(error => from(publicBundlesLoadFail(error))
    )
  ))
)
```

What is the proper way to handle errors using collectionData?

Comment: Have you figured out the 'correct' way handling an error from `collectionData()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`catchError` will catch errors returned by the observable. In your case that is `collectionData`. I'm not familiar with RxFire but if you say that `collectionData emits a result with no elements` then it makes sense for `catchError` to not be called. Empty results is still considered a (successful) result. Try making `collectionData` fail on purpose to see if you'll get an error in `catchError`.

Comment: you hould add your suggestions as a comment , not as an answer.